# getting each line text in navbar and add as id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get each link's text and add it to link as ID.

here is my navbar code:

```html
<div class="navbar">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "i want to get each link's text and add it to link as ID."?

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW How is it not clear?

Comment: This question gains great number of upvotes. wow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wanting this I think-

```js
const links = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')];
links.forEach(link => {
  link.setAttribute('id', link.innerText);
});
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the links using [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method like:

```
$('.navbar a').each(...)
```

Then get each link text using [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) like:

```
$(this).text().trim()  
// .trim() is used to remove whitespace from both sides of this string
```

and finally set the ids using [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) like:

```
$(this).attr('id', value);
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
$('.navbar a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('id', $(this).text().trim());
});
```

```css
[id^='link']{background-color: yellow;text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the link children of the `ul` using `.each` function and set the text of the `a` element as its text in each iteration using the `.attr` function:

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
     $('ul a').each(function(item){
          $(this).attr('id', $(this).text());
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
     <ul>
          <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```